# Wordpress Api won't return all users' fields

Tags: wordpress, api, postman

I am writing a program in Java to access Wordpress data. I use Postman for a better image of the data. When i make a request to get users' data, the response has just a few fields compared to what documentation of Wordpress Api claims. For example, Username, first_name, last_name, email, registered_date, roles, capabilities are not shown in the response.
Can you help with a workaround to get these data?

UPDATE : When i make a post request, the response does have the mentioned fields above. But when i make a get request, doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, you just have to add context argument in the URL. Like this:
wwww.example.com/users?context=edit and will return all fields.

Answer (score 0):

> The REST API provides public data accessible to any client
>   anonymously, **as well as private data only available after
>   authentication.**

[Read more](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/)